# Finding the range of a $y=-x^2(x+5)(x-3)$ without calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization, quartics

I was helping a precalculus student with this question. The graph wasn't given. My only idea was to find the inverse and try to find its domain. When trying to find the inverse, I arrived at $0=y^4+2y^3-15y^2+x$ and I was hoping to be able to factor it. However, besides using the quartic formula, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: If you consider the intermediate value theorem to be "calculus" then maybe you can't do without that.  Otherwise: $y\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\mp\infty$ (each is minus if the other is plus).  That and the intermediate value theorem give you the answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, the limit is $-\infty$ at both ends: this is a quartic, not a cubic.

Comment: I agree.  If $x\to-\infty$, then $x+5$, $x-3$ are both negative, so their product is positive; $x^2$ is always positive; and thus $-x^2(x+5)(x-3)$ is negative.  Thus, my guess is we want a maximum.

Comment: @ForgotALot Right, there is no lower bound, but we are looking for the upper bound which we usually find using the first derivative

Comment: @Ovi: One problem with your approach is that the function doesn't have an inverse, in the first place. (I'm not sure how I would proceed without calculus.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael : oh${}\,\ldots\,{}$I guess sometimes details matter, don't they?  ok, So the hard part is to find the maximum value. $\qquad$

Comment: @CameronBuie Couldn't we have an inverse with a domain restricted to several different intervals, and one of the endpoints of those intervals could give us out desired value for the range?

Comment: @Ovi: Certainly! The problem is determining the domains of said partial inverses.

Comment: @CameronBuie Right, but since those partial inverses are likely to contain square roots, I imagine finding their domain would not be such a hard task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely don't need calculus nor a graphing calculator for this problem. We are trying to find
$$-x^4-2x^3+15x^2=y_{max}$$
Rewrite as
$$x^4+2x^3-15x^2+y_{max}=0$$
Now if we knew where the maximum occurred, say at $x=a$, then $a$ would be a root of this equation. Also it must be a double root of else the graph of the function would cross the $x$-axis at this point, so it wouldn't be a maximum. Thus $(x-a)^2=x^2-2ax+a^2$ must be a factor of $x^4+2x^3-15x^2+y_{max}$. Carrying out polynomial long division, we get a quotient of $$x^2+(2a+2)x+(3a^2+4a-15)$$ and a remainder of $$(4a^3+6a^2-30a)x+y_{max}-(3a^4+4a^3-15a^2)$$
The quotient is of little interest to us, but the remainder must be the zero polynomial, so
$$4a^3+6a^2-30a=2a(2a^2+3a-15)=0$$
Here we can recognize the derivative, but no calculus was harmed in the production of this post! So
$$a\in\left\{0,\frac{-3+\sqrt{129}}4,\frac{-3-\sqrt{129}}4\right\}$$
And since
$$y_{max}=3a^4+4a^3-15a^2$$
We can just test the $3$ roots and get values of $0$, $28.182551$, and $119.754949$ respectively. Thus the max occurs at $a=\frac{-3-\sqrt{129}}4\approx-3.598454$ and has the value $y_{max}=3a^4+4a^3-15a^2\approx119.754949$.

**EDIT**: I thought that it would be tedious be expand that polynomial in $a$ to find the exact value of $y_{max}$, but if we observe that $y_{max}=\frac{u+v\sqrt{129}}{256}\approx119.754949$ and then $\frac{u-v\sqrt{129}}{256}\approx28.182551$, where $u$ and $v$ are integers, we see that $u=128(119.754949+28.182551)=18936=8\cdot2367$ and $v=128(119.754949-28.182551)/\sqrt{129}=1032=8\cdot129$, we only have to be sure of our approximate results for $u$ and $v$ to the nearest integer to obtain the exact result $y_{max}=\frac{2367+129\sqrt{129}}{32}$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Is this not a well-known method? I'm very surprised nobody had posted it yet

Comment: I seem to recall having seen a relatively clean method for showing that the maximum must happen at a zero of the derivative polynomial without calculus in some textbook, but I can't remember where nor reconstruct the proof. A method for getting the exact value of $y_{max}$ relatively painlessly did occur to me, so I edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the function is always negative if $x<-5$ or $x>3$, is equal to zero when $x$ is $-5$ or $3$, and grows in magnitude without bound as $x$ increases past $3$, so the range includes $(-∞,0]$.

Between $-5$ and $3$ the function is positive (except at $0$), so it's a question of finding the maximum achieved in this range. Personally, if I wasn't using calculus, I would graph the function with a graphing calculator, observe that the maximum is about $119.75$, and conclude that the range is approximately $(-\infty, 119.75]$.

Comment: not trying to argue but those parenthesis are needed. If you take a look at the graph $y=x^2$ you should see that all values of x in this equation are positive. Therefore $(-6)^2 = 36$ is what you need to use.

Comment: Ohhhh. Yes indeed you are correct. The mobile app has the equation written with the dollar signs still and the negative sign is hidden in there. I simply read the equation wrong. You are correct @Kundor. Cheers.

Comment: Notice that if you write -5 without MathJax then it looks like -5 instead of like $-5$. (Even worse: if something like 3-5 is written without MathJax, then it looks like 3-5 instead of $3-5$.)  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: "Use a graphing calculator" is not a solution. In my opinion, a proper answer would have a purely algebraic method (something like what one would do with finding the min/max of a quadratic) which gives a closed form. If such a solution is not possible, then the answer should discuss why.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I'm curious why you think it's not a solution. I'm a mathematician, and like I said, it's what I would do. What would you do if we had started with an arbitrary polynomial of degree 7 or so? An algebraic solution would then be impossible, but it's easy to find the solution numerically, which is what the graphing calculator is doing. It was good enough for Newton, why not for us?

Answer (score 1):

First we have to find the zeros of the eqn $y=-(x^2)(x+5)(x-3)$. So from the 
given eqn we get the zeros which are 0 of multiplicity 2,-5 of 1 and 3 of 1.

1.$y>0$ when $-5<x<3$

2.$y<0$ when $-\infty<x<-5\;\;and\;\;3<x<\infty$

3.As $x$ tends to $-\infty$, $y$ tends to $-\infty$ and $x$ tends to +infinty, $y$ tends to -infinity.

Now we have to calculate the max value of $y$.

$y=-(x^2)(x+5)(x-3)$

$\implies$$y=-(x^2)({x^2}+2x-15)$

$\implies$$y=-({x^4}+2{x^3}-15{x^2})$

Then make this term ${x^4}+2{x^3}-15{x^2}$ into of the form

$y=-({f(x)^4})+K_1\;\;where\;\;K_1>0$

Or

$y=-({f(x)^4}+{g(x)^2})+K_2\text{ where }K_2>0$

Then you will get $K_1=K_2$, the max value of $y$.

Then you will get the $R(y)=(-\infty,K_1\;\;OR\;\;K_2$]